# 2 Dimensional Array Loop View in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm newbie to react native and doesn't know how to loop 2 Dimensional Array properly. Currently I'm having problem on creating simple flexbox layout loop that could fetch data from array.

Here's my Image.
[Flexbox Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4YvB.jpg)

My first loop was going for FlexDirection Row which loop 8 datas, and second is for the Column which loop 2 datas.

**The problem is I Can't get all the datas because the main view is on the second loop which is only 2 datas out of 8.**

Here's my Datas and Render function code.

```
var menuHome= [
  {menuName:'menu1',menuImage:'image1'},
  {menuName:'menu2',menuImage:'image2'},
  {menuName:'menu3',menuImage:'image3'},
  {menuName:'menu4',menuImage:'image4'},
  {menuName:'menu5',menuImage:'image5'},
  {menuName:'menu6',menuImage:'image6'},
  {menuName:'menu7',menuImage:'image7'},
  {menuName:'menu8',menuImage:'iamge8'}
]
  render() {
      for(i=1;i<=2;i++){

        if(i%2 !== 0){ 
          menuBox2 = 15;
        }else{
          menuBox2 = 0; 
          l+=1;
        }

        menuBlock2.push(
          <TouchableHighlight 
            style={[styles.menuBox, {marginRight:menuBox2},{backgroundColor:this.state.menuBg}]}
            onPress= { () => {} }
            underlayColor="rgba(138,24,27,1)"
            key = {i}
            >
            <View style={[styles.justify]}>
              <SvgUri
                width="50"
                height="50"
                source={require("AwesomeProject/app/images/balance-01.svg")}
                style={styles.images}
              />
              <Text style={[styles.baseText,{color:this.state.menuText}]}>{menuHome[i].menuName}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )
      }

    for(z=0;z<4;z++){
      menuBlock.push(
        <View style={[styles.mainWrapper, styles.row]} key = {z}>
          {menuBlock2}
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        {menuBlock}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Thank you Guys!

Comment: You have `i <=2 `, it's only going to push the first 3 elements in your `menuHome` array?

Comment: @MattyK14 Yeah that's for the column.
As you can see the first loop is "MenuBlock" which looping the "MenuBlock2". "MenuBlock" is for flexDirection:row and "MenuBlock2" is for the column.

Comment: How could i get all the array data with this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you're pushing your elements into one array, and then you're pushing those exact same elements into another array from the previous.

Comment: Which elements do you want positioned where based on the image you provided?

Comment: Nevermind, i solved it by myself by map function with flexWrap : wrap, set width of the box, and remove the menuBlock2 iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you could also simply use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) to display your View through the `rederItem` method prop and set `numColumns={2}`.